# Create custom thread queue with limited number of threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool

We have a windows service which process messages from our queue.
Each message contains a crud execution string to db.

Until now we used ThreadPool with setting max threads to configurable number.

After seeing the problems it made and reading a couple of post against using ThreadPool for long opearations , we are looking for better solution for limiting our max number of threads.

Do you have a good solution to suggest?

Comment: Why is the operation long running? Is it because you are CPU constrained, or is it because you're blocking on IO?

Comment: The db execution can take some time because we have a lot of information in out tables (let say..more than a simple calculation).

Comment: So your app is waiting on the DB? How are you doing your DB access? Any chance of making your queries async? If so, you could carry on with the ThreadPool.

Comment: We use ado.net to access our db.
It can`t be async because the information will not be reliable this way. 
Do you know solutions other that thread pool?

Comment: "because the information will not be reliable" I don't buy this at all. There's no reason why async would not be as reliable as synchronous methods, and using async methods is the usual way to avoid ThreadPool starvation. However, if you are sure that this isn't something that you'd like to pursue, you could look into https://github.com/amibar/SmartThreadPool . Seems hacky to me. Prefer async over sync every time, especially when dealing with ThreadPool starvation.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the fase answers.

Second, i read about smart thread pool but heard it is not fit for long tasks. This is the reason i think i will pass on it.

If you disagree with it i will be glad to hear a different opinion.